# How does the file system: (Ubuntu 22.04) Read: 792,136 files [140.8 TB]?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

While attempting to backup and copy my current stable settings from root, I ran into an issue where this popped up:

[image]

Basically I created a separate partition, (same disk) installed ubuntu onto this partition, (logged into main partition) logged in as root, opened the newly installed os on the second partition, removed and attempted to copy [main partition] file system over, recieving error message, (not enough space).

Size of this disk: 256GB
Bios: 99MB
EFI:  99MB
Main Partition: 119GB  <----Main
(3) Swap Areas 1.4GB ea.
Secondary Partition One 66GB
Secondary Partition Two 66GB  <---- Test

Comment: I actually found this folder to be the culprit: [proc] 137,321 items, totalling 140,7 TB: https://imagetolink.com/ib/qUuKWDwdcP

Comment: `/proc` is a system directory that you're not supposed to back up - and you can't really count on its size.

Comment: What is kcore: https://imagetolink.com/ib/OpZ3BX5eGF